# Ember.js/Emblem.js Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'createUser'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I think I'm probably misunderstanding the way the Ember hooks up routes, views, and templates, but I can't figure out while the following results in the error:

> Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'createUser'.

My files are as follows:

javascripts/router.js.coffee

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'account', ->
    @route 'index', path: '/'
```

javascripts/routes/account_router.js.coffee

```
App.AccountRoutes = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.User.find()
```

javascripts/controllers/account_controller.js.coffee

```
App.AccountController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  createUser: ->
    App.User.createRecord
      field1: @get('field1')
      / etc
```

javascripts/views/account_view.js.coffee

```
App.AccountView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: 'account'
```

javascripts/templates/account/index.emblem

```
form.form submit="createUser"
  / fields
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not a coffescript dude but there is a typo in your route declaration for one: Routes should be Route

You put:

```
App.AccountRoutes = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.User.find()
```

Should be:

```
App.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend
 model: -> App.User.find()
```

And if you are trying to access the index route of the account resource you dont have to explicitly define it in the router its just there. So you would use your AccountIndexController, AccountIndexRoute, and account/index template to access it.

Comment: Coming from a Rails background, I had assumed that if I defined an `AccountController` the routes under it would be able to inherit the methods from there. Am I going to need to redefine a new controller for each template?

Comment: Ember uses naming conventions too like Rails to help you keep all these Routes, Controllers, Templates, Views so you can remember what goes with each other. AccountController by default unless overridden by you is going to be associated with your AccountRoute, and Account(Template) what happens in Account(Template) is going to bubble to AccountController AccountRoute and keep going up the tree to the application level. You do not have to redefine a Controller for each template unless you are adding functionality to the default behavior that Ember uses for the controllers to just run.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are missing the `actions` hash.

Actions inside of templates like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="foo">
  <div {{action "doFoo"}}>Click here</div>
</script>
```

Need to be present in your corresponding controller or route, inside of a actions object:

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    doFoo: function() {
      alert('Foo');
    }
    // ... more actions here
  }
});
```

In your case I think that you need to update to the following:

```
App.AccountController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    createUser: ->
      App.User.createRecord
        field1: @get('field1')
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer was actually @rick's suggestion, but I was getting deprecation warnings that were fixed by adding the method to an actions object as you suggest

Comment: Good eye Marcio the action hash was missing as well. Group programming at work here. The deprecation warning (events...something something) you were getting @jonathan was because of missing action hash when app reached that Controller looking for createUser.

Answer (score 0):

Coffeescript is really sensitive to indentation and is probably misinterpreting your controller. Try this:

```
App.AccountController = Ember.ObjectController.extend   
  createUser: ->
    App.User.createRecord
      field1: @get('field1')
      / etc
```

Comment: Sorry, that was actually just a copy/paste mistake, I've edited my question to reflect that